# If p is a prime, $a,c\in\mathbb{Z}$,$n\in\mathbb{N}$,$m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $b\in\mathbb{Z}$,is there exists $a\frac{b}{p^m}-\frac{c}{p^n}\in\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: ring-theory, modular-arithmetic, divisibility

Suppose we are given the following:
$p$ is a prime number;
$a, c \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $ n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Can I prove that there exists $m \in \mathbb{N} $ and $b \in  \mathbb {Z} $ such that

$\displaystyle a\frac{b}{p^m}- \frac{c}{p^n} \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Answer (score 1):

Sure.  If $c$ has $n$ or more factors of $p$, just choose $m=1,b=p$ and you are done.  Find how many factors of $p$ are in $a,c$, call the result $r,s$.  Let $m=n-s+r$  Then $abp^{n-m}$ and $c$ have the same number of factors of $p$, so you can find a solution to $abp^{n-m}-c\equiv 0 \pmod {p^n}$

Answer (score 1):

We will get rid of cases where $\gcd(a,p)>1$: by factoring out $p^\alpha$ as necessary, you can write $a=p^\alpha a'$, and you have now to find $b$ and $m$ such that

$$a'\frac{b}{p^{m-\alpha}} - \frac{c}{p^{n}} \in \Bbb Z$$

So, let's assume $\gcd(a,p)=1$.

And let's try to solve the problem with $m=n$:

$$\frac{ab}{p^n}-\frac{c}{p^n} \in \Bbb Z$$

This would simply mean that

$$ac \equiv b \pmod {p^n}$$

And since $\gcd(a,p)=1$, it has an inverse $\bmod \; p^n$, thus you just have to pick $b\equiv a^{-1}c \pmod{p^n}$.